# how can I consume an endpoint annotated with @Suspended using postman or curl?

Tags: java, postman, jax-ws

I am testing some code that has an annotation I haven't used before and reading the documentation seems like I should not even send any parameter to call it, but I might.

The endpoint looks like this:

```
@POST
    @Path("/hello")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void postHello(
        @Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse,@QueryParam("dtd") String name, String obj) {
    ...
}
```

So by now I am using *Postman* or *cURL* and sending this:

```
curl -X POST \
  'http://localhost:9000/hello?name=John' \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Host: localhost:8080' \
  -d '{}'
```

Unfortunately, I get an error **400 Bad Request**

Any idea what header I am missing? or might be `@Produces`/`@Consumes`?

Comment: Anything in logs?

Comment: not really, i cannot access the logs to test it :s

Comment: Could you give a little more context? If you could create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), that'd be excellent. Maybe a git repo with the java code and a gist with a sample request (postman json or cURL is fine)

Comment: Are you using any pre-request filter before hitting this endpoint? It could be related to the accept-encoding, cache-control but I can't be 100% sure unless I see the log. Can you please provide postman log (Windows) CTRL+ALT+C?

Comment: When you have `@QueryParam("dtd") String name` don't you have to pass `dtd` in your url instead of `name`?

Comment: Hi Sujti, it was actually an issue, realized I had two problems, but mainly I was not seeing that dtd :D